# view presist in same location after rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-xml

I'm building camera activity in my app 
and try to make the shutter button to placed in same location
no matter device rotation, like all the camera apps...
but my layout is rotating when device rotates and the button moves
(I don't want to use android:screenOrientation="portrait")

how can I make the button stay in same place and just rotate accordingly,
without invoking android activity lifecycle at rotation?

Comment: Can you show screenshots and the layout code (most likely XML) that creates it? Then describe what you want to look different than what actual happens?

Comment: [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/26n6ymSxIhR752CSQ/giphy.gif) is what i want to achive 
[this](https://media.giphy.com/media/xT39Dg3q1vh8ldu8Wk/giphy.gif) is what i have now

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout-land and  put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

Comment: i did this but than the layout reloads (activity lifecycles..)

Comment: then u can You could lock the activity in one orientation by adding android:screenOrientation="portrait" (or "landscape") to <activity> in your manifest. and use sensor permission android to get change oranatation to start animate rotate button.